# Fast access to numpy.ndarray

Tags: numpy, optimization, cython

I have two snippets of cython code (I use ipython here):

```
%%cython --cplus 
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

def autoregr5(np.ndarray[np.float64_t,ndim=1] arr,np.float64_t alph):
    cdef vector[float] vec;
    vec.reserve(arr.size)
    vec.push_back(arr[0])
    for i from 1 <= i < (arr.size):
        vec.push_back(vec.back() * alph + arr[i])
    return vec


%%cython --cplus 
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False) 
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.overflowcheck(False)
@cython.initializedcheck(False)
def autoregr6(np.ndarray[np.float64_t,ndim=1] arr,np.float64_t alph):
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t,ndim=1] result =     np.zeros(arr.size,dtype = np.float64)
    result[0]=arr[0]
    for i from 1 <= i < (arr.size):
       result[i] = result[i-1] * alph + arr[i]
    #arr[i]
    return result
```

And the problem is that autoregr6 takes 2.2 s to run on a np.array of 1e7 floats ( which is comparable to python equivalent), while for autoregr5 it takes only 250 ms on my machine (i7 4790, ubuntu 14, python 3.4, cython 0.23).
Operations like this seem especially time consuming:

```
result[i] = result[i-1]
```

while these:

```
result[i] = arr[i]
```

are executed very quickly. Could you tell me how to make this faster?

Comment: I think all you're missing is `cdef Py_ssize_t i` to make sure it knows that `i` is a C integer rather than a Python object. It can infer this sometimes (but not 100% reliably) so perhaps this is why you get different results.

Comment: @DavidW Yes, that did the job. Now numpy version runs 40 ms.Thank you very much!